# Is there an alternative to oci_bind_by_name and having to define a maxlength when using an OUT bind?

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

Our current setup is to use `oci_bind_by_name` when retrieving data from an Oracle database. However, in doing so we must define a `maxlength` to set the maximum length of the data so that PHP allocates enough memory to hold the returned value. This is cumbersome and a manual task to check our data to see what size to use; if our data changes it may also mean going back to either increase and decrease this value all of which isn't very good.

My question is therefore: in PHP, is there another way of achieving the same thing with the OCI8 extension or indeed by using another?

Comment: You could profile the database table/ column sizes and use those values as estimated size parameters in PHP. Do you have maximum column / row size estimates for your selected table / columns? Are there any 'blob' columns that may need to be addresses separately?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Ryan. Good idea profiling the column size but PHP can be just as fussy (about the memory allocation) and complain if you overestimate and allocate the maximum possible size to every value returned in OUT. No blobs to contend with, no. The only way I know of to get around our problem is to use cursors where you don't have to specify a maxlength but that means rewriting all of our PL/SQL to be in cursors.